# Can I update a variable URL in a loop so it can run without me manually inputting new URL in beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Once I set my variable URL for beautifulsoup to scrape, can I update that variable URL in a loop so it can run without me manually inputting the new URL in beautifulsoup package in python?

I tried making a loop so it would pull the new URL out of the original URL and my update original URL with the new URL that i pulled out of the website. I was able to get it running without any errors. My problem is that it wont update the original URL with the new URL that was scraped from the website. Hoping to find some beautifulSoup experts :)

Heres my code:

```
url = "https://www.academy.com/c/academy-clearance &facet=%27facet_Product%20Type%27:%27Shoes%27"
while url:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Extract necessary links
    links = set()
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        href = link.get('href')
        if href and href.startswith("/p/"):
            full_link = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, href)  # Construct absolute URL
            links.add(full_link)
        
    # Output the links
    for link in links:
        print(link)

    # Find the link to the next page
    next_page_element = soup.find('a', {'data-auid': 'gotoNextPage'})
    if next_page_element:
        next_page_link = next_page_element.get('href')
        next_page_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, next_page_link)  # Construct absolute URL
        print("Next Page Link:", next_page_url)
        url = next_page_url
    else:
        print("No next page link found.")
        break
```

So my goal is to scrape a website and extract product details, and at the end of the code im looking for the next page link. I want to be able to update my original URL variable with the next page link.

Comment: We'll need more. What is the url, how would you like to update it? Share your code.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course you can do that.  If you showed some code, and explained exactly what you want, we might be able to show you an example of how to do it.

Comment: `for i in range(10): url = f'/base/url/{i}' ...`

Comment: Always check your response -> `Please verify you are a human`

Comment: It looks like this code already reassigns `url` in the loop.  So what is the actual problem?